# Why am I returned undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr, rangy

I am wanting to get an attribute of the parent element that my cursor is inside of.

I have been totally unsuccessful for about two hours now, so I'm posting to see if anybody has any suggestions. This is the function I have but don't know why `parentID` only returns undefined:

```
function getAttrOfParent() {
    var newRange = rangy.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var parentElement = newRange.commonAncestorContainer;
    var parentID = $(parentElement).attr('id');
    alert(parentID);
}
```

This works fine to get the text of the parent element...

```
function getTextOfParent() {
    var newRange = rangy.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var parentElement = newRange.commonAncestorContainer;
    var parentText = $(parentElement).text();
    alert(parentText);
}
```

...and this works fine to get the title of a specified element.

```
function getAttrOfElement() {
    var parentID = $('#1').attr('id');
    alert(parentID);
}
```

[Here's my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/circleb/5yzGU/), you have to click inside of the text area for the first two functions to work.

Comment: In your fiddle, you are using `.attr('title')` instead of `.attr('id')`. The latter works fine. But maybe I don't understand what exactly you want. You have a couple of `p` elements in there, which neither have an `id` nor a `title` attribute. So of course you get `undefined`.

Comment: Your first function is crashing because of a rangy error: `uncaught DOM exception: INDEX_SIZE_ERR`

Comment: @Felix Kling I fixed the fiddle, but `.attr('id')` doesn't work still.

Comment: @CircleB: See the edit to my comment.

Comment: @Felix Kling Yes I know I'll get undefined for those, in my full function I'm checking to see if I'm in a span before doing this function...I stripped all of that for simplicity sake.

Comment: Maybe you should not simplify too much.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry about that... I was trying to zero in on my issue and got too narrow minded. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parentElement = newRange.commonAncestorContainer` isn't giving you the parent element, it is giving you the parent *node*.

This is fairly obvious if you `console.log(parentElement)` to see what is being selected.

If you select text entirely inside one of your spans (which have ids) then you get the *text* node (which doesn't have an id).

If you select more text, you get the paragraph element node (which doesn't have an id).

You might want to try something like `var parentElement = $(newRange.commonAncestorContainer).parents('span');`

Comment: That works perfectly! P.S. I'm not familiar with javascript and didn't know that you could log like that, thanks for the tip!